# Adding vba or vbscript support to .NET application

Tags: .net, vba, vbscript

I believe Microsoft stops licensing VBA scripting for application which however is still used in their latest Office products although I assume they are discouraging people from using it.
Our .NET application needs VBA (better) or VBScript (second choice) support for backward compatibility reason. Any suggestions on doing that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn707392.aspx

Comment: Microsoft Script Control add VBScript/JScript to applications. It is ONLY in the 32 bit folder so you need to wrap it in an exe (dllhost) to use from 64 bit or compile to 32 bit. msscript.ocx.

Comment: The implication of "no longer licensed" is that you can't get the runtime deployed onto the user's machine.  It has been 10 years so fuggedaboudid.  VBScript and JScript can still be done, add a COM reference to "Microsoft Script Control 1.0" to get a reference to the [MSScriptControl type library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227633(v=vs.60).aspx).  It tends to be rough on programmers familiar with VBScript, there is no equivalent of the commonly used WScript object.

Answer (score 0):

VBA and VBScript are COM enabled languages.  If you want them to talk to a .NET application then the .NET application needs to ship a COM interface.

Excel, Word and other Office applications continue to have VBA environments and will continue to serve as clients.   Bolting on VBA onto your application is, as you say, deprecated.

But Python is also COM enabled, so you could write a Python script in a free edition (Community Edition) of Visual Studio if your users demand an IDE other than an Office application.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. Right now I think my best solution is to find something that is as close to VBA as possible and preferably free. I know unless I can support VBA natively, I would have to do some kind of conversion anyway, but the closer this script language is to VBA, the less conversion or incompatibility it will be.